# Python2.7 - CSV DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I have a question about how to properly read a CSV file so that you can apply the techniques that exist in NLTK. My goal was to make the CSV file line by line and not as just a single line.

My first attempt was with: `file= open("data/MyFile.csv")`. My .csv file has 40k+ rows. That way I realized that my purpose did not fit very well and I changed it to:

```
 import csv
import preprocessing
from preprocessing import PreProcessing
def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')
def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                            dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

with open("data/MyFile.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
    #I had to remove the Sniffer, because even without indicating a delimiters it was giving error that it did not find a delimiters.
    #dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
    #csvfile.seek(0)
    lower_stream = (line.lower() for line in csvfile) #Normalizing. Putting all text in tiny
    #Reading the file
    corpus = csv.DictReader(unicode_csv_reader(lower_stream), fieldnames='status_message',dialect ='excel')

def status_processing(corpus):

    myCorpus = preprocessing.PreProcessing()
    myCorpus.text = corpus
    myCorpus.initial_processing()
```

`fieldnames='status_message'` This is the field I want to read. Status message is the header, it is used to identify the texts contained in the csv

After that, I start applying techniques to make NLTK easier to use in my text, one of them is BeautifulSoup.

The way I do it is displayed in the `def status_processing(corpus)`.

The invoked method of the other script is constructed like this:

```
tokens = None
    def initial_processing(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.text,"html.parser")
        self.text = soup.get_text()
        #Todo Se quiser salvar os links mudar aqui
        self.text = re.sub(r'(http://|https://|www.)[^"\' ]+', " ", self.text)
        self.tokens = self.tokenizing(1, self.text)
        pass
```

This way, when I run the script the error message is displayed:

```
line 39, in initial_processing
    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.text,"html.parser")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 176, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256:
AttributeError: DictReader instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

How can I do that so I read the CSV file line by line without there being this error?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow everything, but ... `DictReader` doesn't have a length.  `BeautifulSoup` expects that whatever object (presumably a string type) you pass as the argument `markup` does have a length.  Perhaps you mean to pass only a single line at a time to `BeautifulSoup` rather than passing it the `DictReader` instance? I would also advise against naming your DictReader 'text' since it is definitely not text. Good use of names helps a lot in understanding code when reading it, and in writing correct code.

Comment: @dsh The `.text` Is part of my builder. Is there any way I can read row by line through csv.reader ()

Comment: Yes: `csv.reader()` returns the data row by row.  So: `for row in csv.reader(...): print(row)` would read row by row.

Comment: Interesting. I need to pick up each line and step inside the `def status_processing(corpus)` So I can work and use the NLTK techniques on each line. One of them is for the correction of words. If I pass the entire document it will take a long time, since it is a costly algorithm. Does it work with reader () that I can achieve this goal?

Comment: I know python and csv, but I am unfamiliar with NLTK and BeautifulSoup. It may help if you edit your question to contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (note that this will contain the necessary sample input files too).